# Module not found when requiring express

Tags: node.js, express, npm

Server is Ubuntu 12.0.4 x64, Node.js version is v0.8.9 (built from source code). I have succesfully installed `express` by `sudo npm install -g express` then tried below sample code to verify `express` but get error saying "**Can not find module 'express'**"

```
var express = require('express');
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing a node.js global module](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585447/accessing-a-node-js-global-module)

Answer (score 2):

You've installed the module *globally*. To use it in your project you need to install it locally. From your project directory:

```
npm install express
```

Or, add it to the dependencies in your *package.json* file and just run `npm install`. This will create a *node_modules* directory in your project, into which all local modules will be installed.

Comment: Could I know why this module should be installed locally rahter than globally as others?

Comment: Some modules can be installed both globally and locally. With Express installed globally you can run `express` in your terminal and it will initialize an Express project. When it's installed locally, you can use Express in that project.

Comment: It just depends on how you set `$NODE_PATH`, I can require globally installed modules just fine because the global `node_modules` (which, in my case, is located in `/usr/local/lib`) is in `$NODE_PATH`.